# Similar to Block Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find matrix form of an operator on a vector space V which is direct sum of its two subspaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182015/how-to-find-matrix-form-of-an-operator-on-a-vector-space-v-which-is-direct-sum-o)

So Let's say I have a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ which is n dimensional, and additionally that I have $V=B\oplus C$ with $B$ and $C$ subspaces.  If I have a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that restricted to either of these subspaces, $T$ is invariant, then obviously we have a matrix in $F^{n\times n}$ corresponding to $T$.  I've seen the claim that if we form the matrix $Q$ whose left-most columns are a basis for $B$ and the rest a basis for $C$ that $Q^{-1}TQ$ is block diagonal.  I've never quite understood why this was true, nor have I been able to prove it...Certainly this is important for proving the existence of Jordan Normal Forms etc, so I'd like to be able to justify the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$ where $\{v_0,\dots,v_k\}$ is a basis for $B$ and $\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $C$. Ignoring the fact that $T$ is not actually a matrix, what you mean by the matrix "$Q^{-1}TQ$" is the matrix for $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $D$. Write
$$[T]_D=\begin{bmatrix}T_{1,1} & T_{1,2} \\ T_{2,1} & T_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $T_{1,1}$ is a $k \times k$ matrix and $T_{2,2}$ is a $(n-k) \times (n-k)$ matrix. You say that $B$ is $T$-invariant, so $Tv \in B$ for all $v \in B$. In other words,
$$[T]_D \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} w \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
for all $k \times 1$ vectors $v_1$. Now you can deduce that $T_{2,1}=0$. Using the fact that $C$ is $T$-invariant, you can deduce that $T_{1,2}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the link you're missing is that, if a matrix $Q$ contains a basis $Q=[b_1|...|b_n]$ as its *column vectors*, then for any given matrix $T$, the matrix of lin.transformation $v\mapsto Tv$ *in the basis $(b_1,...,n_n)$* is just $Q^{-1}TQ$.

And this is because,

1. $\ TQ=T[b_1|..|b_n] = [Tb_1|..|Tb_n]$
2. $Q\cdot\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \end{pmatrix} = \sum_i\alpha_ib_i$
3. $Q^{-1}(\sum_i \alpha_ib_i) = \sum_i\alpha_i\cdot Q^{-1}b_i = \sum_i\alpha_ie_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th member of the standard basis in $F^n$.
4. So, altogether $Q^{-1}TQ$ is just the matrix of $T$ written in the new basis.